# Memory leak binding to dependency property

Tags: c#, xaml, memory-leaks, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have a memory leak in a Windows 8.1 Store App where I have my own grid control inside a UserControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rows, ElementName=ThisUserControl}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{Binding GridControlCellDataTemplate, ElementName=ThisUserControl}"></ContentControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Rows, Cells and GridControlCellDataTemplate are all DependencyProperties and the CellDataTemplate I use for this scenario is empty:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GridControlCellDataTemplate"></DataTemplate>
```

Each time i change the Rows-property to a new ObservableCollection the memory goes up, and isn't being cleared.

Is it not possible to bind it this way? Or am I looking at the wrong place for the leak? If I remove the ContentControl, the leak goes away.

Comment: Why create new ObservableCollections in stead of updating the one that is already being used?

Comment: @Max Well, if I continue running the app, the memory usage increases indefinately, and after a while the app becomes sluggish. I would say it's a memory leak.

Comment: @ThaMe90 I think that would probably would be one way to fix it. None the less, the memory should be able to be cleared, right?

Comment: I believe @ThaMa90 has the correct suggestion. If you look on the net this seems to be a problem also with Silverlight. (Winrt xaml is based on Silverlight). See [here](http://neverindoubtnet.blogspot.com/2010/08/observablecollection-datagrid-memory.html) for one example. My Win 8 app also had the leaks until I stopped creating new collections, and just reused the existing one.